# Program to count number of letters in string as command line argument

Tags: python

First, **I don't want some code to copy-paste. I want to know how to approach that problem.** I'm in the process of learning how to program, and I'm rather confused on when to use loop, I don't know if this is the correct approach.

Now, here is the problem I try to solve: *"Write a program to count number of letters in string as command line argument and print out the percentage of the most common letter in the string (if there are letters of equal frequency print out all that are equal)"*

Comment: `collections.Counter(some_text).most_common()`

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to make your point more clear. Feel free to revert that edit if you feel so.

Answer (score 3):

You should break the task down into sub tasks that you can handle one by one.

1. How to accept user input.
2. How get the length of that user input.
3. How to store each character.
4. How to store and count how many times each character appears.
5. From the stored character counts, find the most frequent.

In solving these steps if you find the need to iterate through your user input, use a loop.  See the below for examples.

Loops are used when you have some data to iterate through.  For instance:

```
commands = ["say hello","1 + 1","exit","this command would never be reached"]
for command in commands:
    if command == "say hello":
        print "hello"
    elif command == "1 + 1":
        print 2
    elif command == "exit":
        break
```

You could do it to check data for certain numbers:

```
data = [1, 2, 3]
for n in data:
    if n == 2:
        print "Found a 2!"
```

You could do it to sort data:

```
# separate all the upper, lower, and non-alphabet characters
letters = "AbCdEfGhI!@"
uppercase = []
lowercase = []
other = []
for letter in letters:
    if letter.isupper():
        uppercase.append(letter)
    elif letter.islower():
        lowercase.append(letter)
    else:
        other.append(letter)
        lowercase.append(letter)
```

`while` loops are used in a similar fashion, generally you use `for` loops for things of a known, finite range, and `while` loops for tasks where the number of iterations may not be fixed.

```
 data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 while len(data) > 0:
     if data[-1] == 5:
         print data.pop()
         data.append(4)
     else:
         print data.pop()
```

You can also use `while` loops in the place of `for` loops

```
 i = 0
 while i < 10:
     print i
     i += 1

 for i in xrange(10):
     print i
```

The two loops above do equivalent tasks, printing the numbers from `0-9`